# start pdb in post mortem mode. any trick to avoid typing "c"

Tags: python, pdb

I'd like to create a small helper (e.g. a shell function), that allows me to call any python script in pdb post mortem mode.

```
withpdb() {
    cmd="$1" ; shift
    python -m pdb -- "$(which $cmd)" "$@"
}
```

So if I typed for example

```
mycmd.py param1 param2
```

and I encounter errors, that I want to analyze with pydb. 
I just go up in my bash history and prefix with `withpdb`

```
withpbd mycmd.py param1 param2
```

Now pdb is started with my script and as soon as I press `c` and return the script starts.

My question is:
Is there any trick to avoid typing the initial "c" + enter?

If I have to write some wrapper code in python or another alngauge, that's also OK

Comment: I suppose you could try something like `echo c | python -m pdb -- $(which $cmd) "$@"`.  (Nevermind, just tried that and it didn't work since the process exits when it hits the end of stdin)

Comment: yep the problem is to inject one "c" + enter but then give control to the console.
one could probably play with except scripts but this seems to be a little bit heavy 
and I wondered whether thre is a mehtod to tell pdb to source some startup commands. Iill dive into the doc a little later.

Comment: Unrelated, but quote the parameters expansions in your function. It will unnecessarily fail if you ever have a pathname containing whitespace or glob characters. `python -m pub -- "$(which "$cmd")" "$@"`. Ironically, `cmd=$1` would be fine, as expansions in the right-hand side of an assignment do not undergo word splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Good to know. Will change

Comment: `{ echo c; cat; } | withpdb ...` should work; standard error would stay open as long as `cat` stays open, but you would lose any editing capabilities the shell might provide that `cat` does not. (You could put the pipe inside the function, but probably not worth doing for the reason just described.)

Comment: I tried that as well, but it messes up the prompt a bit and also seems to break readline support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-c` option to execute `c` upon startup. (And since you only have to write the function once, use `continue` instead of the abbreviation for clarity.)

```
withpdb() {
  cmd="$1" ; shift
  python -m pdb -c continue -- "$(which $cmd)" "$@"
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works (and note that it only seems to work on Python 3).

Comment: It was introduced in Python 3.2, actually. I don't address Python 2 anymore unless the question specifically mentions it.

Comment: Great. works as expected.
Using py2 still for a few months but mostly py3, so no issue it works only from 3.2 onwards